# PrettyFaces and Rewrite libraries - how can we call a bean method before PrettyFaces sets attributes from URL query parameters?

Tags: prettyfaces

We use Prettyfaces and Rewrite library in our JSF project.

Is there a way how we can reset bean attributes (set them to null) before PrettyFaces sets these attributes' values from query parameters in the URL? 
I.e. can we call a method on the bean before PrettyFaces sets the values?

Comment: Which scope are you using? With Rewrite you should usually use the request scope, for which this problem doesn't occur.

Comment: We use Session scope, therefore we need to reset properties.

Comment: Clarified the question and removed duplication.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this, I believe the simplest way would be to Inject the Bean into a RewriteConfiguration object. You'll need to make sure the priority is overridden such that this provider occurs before the built-in PrettyFaces functionality (I believe -10 should do, but you may need to play with this value):

```
public class ExampleConfigurationProvider extends HttpConfigurationProvider
{
   @Inject
   private MySessionBean bean;

   @Override
   public int priority()
   {
      return -10;
   }

   @Override
   public Configuration getConfiguration(final ServletContext context)
   {
      return ConfigurationBuilder.begin()
          .addRule()
          .when(Path.matches("/my-path").and(Direction.isInbound()))
          .perform(new HttpOperation() {
             @Override
             public void performHttp(HttpServletRewrite event, EvaluationContext context)
             {
                bean.clearValues();
             }
          });
   }
}
```

```

Note, the `.when()` rule can contain any conditions that you want.

There are probably other ways of doing this, but this is the simplest I could think of.

Comment: Thank you Lincoln. Can be `ExampleConfigurationProvider` spring bean and @RewriteConfiguration together? I found information that Spring beans which extend `HttpConfigurationProvider` will automatically picked up by Rewrite for configuration. But this doesn't work.

Comment: You need to add the https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/tree/master/integration-spring module. If that doesn't work, you may want to look at the 4 classes and implement a version for your Spring container! PRs welcome! Alternatively you can access the spring context in the ConfigurationProvider manually to construct or request the beans you want programmatically using the Spring APIs.

Comment: What if i have `ViewScoped` Bean? When i inject the bean i get **`ContextNotActiveException: WebBeans context with scope type annotation @ViewScoped does not exist within current thread`**

Comment: @arash You can't use a `ViewScoped` bean before the view has been created. This is why PrettyFaces defers injection & action method for view-scoped objects until during the JSF lifecycle. See the following test for how to create a `HttpConfigurationProvider` to do that: https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/blob/master/integration-faces/src/test/java/org/ocpsoft/rewrite/faces/DeferredOperationTestConfigurationProvider.java#L31

Comment: @arash Or, for the simpler approach: https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/blob/master/integration-cdi-tests/src/test/java/test/org/ocpsoft/rewrite/cdi/action/DeferredActionsBean.java#L60

Comment: Thanks , i solved my problem by reading this: [**Can I pass an Object to a viewscoped bean?**](https://www.ocpsoft.org/support/topic/can-i-pass-an-object-to-a-viewscoped-bean/). thanks for your links. [**Rewrite**](https://www.ocpsoft.org/rewrite/) is a excellent module but for me, is hard to find what i want. Is there something like `PhaseOperation` class for evaluation in the `HttpCondition` class? i want to access the `ViewScoped` bean in the `when()` method.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Yes, there is a `DeferredOperation` that accepts a `Phase` parameter. See my link two comments above. Here it is again :) https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/blob/master/integration-faces/src/test/java/org/ocpsoft/rewrite/faces/DeferredOperationTestConfigurationProvider.java#L43

Comment: Thanks for your attention and patience, Lincoln. What i wont is getting **friendly URL** and **actual URL** from the `ViewScoped` bean to avoid hardcoding URLs in the **ConfigurationProvider**. is there a way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at the annotations module: https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/blob/master/config-annotations/src/test/java/org/ocpsoft/rewrite/annotation/join/JoinParameterBean.java#L10